# I need help creating a pop up holding a form

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck creating a pop up for this form:

```
<form action="https://www.e-act.nl/ah/action" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="admin_id" value="3539"/>
<input type="hidden" name="trigger_code" value="SUBSCR_1607214759431"/>
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="false"/>
<input type="hidden" name="relation_avg1_text" id="relation_avg1_text" value="Ik heb het privacy reglement"/>
<input type="hidden" name="relation_avg1_url" id="relation_avg1_url" value="https://www.tomanage.eu/disclaimer-privacy"/>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">

<table>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_firstName" class=" ar_req">Voornaam</label></td></div>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_lastName" class=" ar_req">Achternaam</label></td></div>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_firstName" name="relation_firstName" placeholder="" value=""/></td></div>
<td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_lastName" name="relation_lastName" placeholder="" value="" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_companyName" class=" ar_req">Bedrijf</label></td></tr></div>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_companyName" name="relation_companyName" placeholder="" value=""/></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_email" class=" ar_req">E-mailadres</label></td></div>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_phone" class=" ar_req">Telefoon</label></td></div>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><input type="email" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_email" name="relation_email" placeholder="" value=""/></div></td>
<td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_phone" name="relation_phone" placeholder="" value="" /></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_3539_FF1607214508718" class=" ar_req">Ik heb interesse in:</label>

<select class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_3539_FF1607214508718" name="relation_3539_FF1607214508718"><option value="Improve">Improve</option><option value="Improve & Act">Improve & Act</option><option value="Improve & Act Plus">Improve & Act Plus</option></select><span class="help-block help">Duid via de dropdown aan welk pakket jouw interesse heeft.</span></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><label for="relation_3539_FF1606468844958" class=" ar_req">Waar kan ik je mee helpen?</label>
<textarea class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="relation_3539_FF1606468844958" name="relation_3539_FF1606468844958" placeholder="" rows="4" cols="100"></textarea></div></tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="relation_avg1" name="relation_avg1"/>&nbsp;Ik heb het privacy reglement <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tomanage.eu/disclaimer-privacy">hier gelezen.</a> </tr>
<tr>
<td><button title="klik hier" type="submit" onclick="return checkSUBSCR_1607214759431(this.form);" class="btn" style="padding:15px;border:0px solid #005493;border-radius:4px;color:#FFFFFF!important;font-family:Dosis; font-size:20px; line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;background-color:#daab01!important;width:70%;">Versturen</button></td></tr>
</form></table>
<script><div class="emailField" style="display:none!important;">dit veld niet invullen s.v.p.<input type="text" name="emailaddress"/></div></form></div></div><script type="text/javascript">
 function checkSUBSCR_1607214759431(form) {
  var missing = false;
  var avg = false;
  var missingFields = '';
  for (i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_firstName') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nVoornaam';
    }
   }
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_lastName') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nAchternaam';
    }
   }
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_companyName') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nBedrijf';
    }
   }
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_email') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nE-mailadres';
    }
   }
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_phone') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nTelefoon';
    }
   }
   if (form.elements[i].name === 'relation_3539_FF1606468844958') {
    if (form.elements[i].value === '') {
     missing = true;
     missingFields = missingFields + '\nWaar kan ik je mee helpen?';
    }
   }
  }
  if (missing) {
   alert('De onderstaande velden moeten zijn ingevuld:\n' + missingFields);
   return false;
  }
  if (!form.elements["relation_avg1"].checked) {
   alert('Er is geen toestemming gegeven');
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
</script>
```

This form needs to be in a button in a pricetable (i created this in html, let me know if you need to see this) when clicked this form needs to open in a form.
You can view the pricetables on this site https://www.tomanage.eu/kmo-paketten i now have a pop up on the "meer info" button but it's not the way it should be. i now created the pop up using a link but should be different. see the pop up below from calendly.
Thanks to anyone who knows or can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Hello Edina and welcome! I can see the popup when I click "meer info" button on the page you've provided within pricetables, but what I'm trying to understand is this part of your question `but it's not the way it should be`. It helps being very specific in explaining the steps and the final result you're expecting. Also I'm seeing a "form" within a "form" element in your code, maybe that's what's causing your issue?

Comment: It sounds like you want a "modal". If you're willing to include the jQuery library in your project, this can be achieved quite easily using any of available plugins such as this one: https://jquerymodal.com/